# I'm pursing my Masters Degree in India, how can I apply for Doctors degree in Japan?

Tags: phd, india, japan

I have pursued my Bachelor's Degree in Civil Engineering from NIT Puducherry. I thought to do my Master degree in Japan, but due to improper planning, I couldn't achieve it. I'm currently pursuing my Master's Degree(in my first year) in IIT Roorkee, in the Department of Earthquake Engineering.
Please help me out with that, how can I at least do my Doctor's from Japan in Earthquake Engineering.

- Procedure to applying for Doctor's in Japan?
- Details regarding Cost of living and Culture in Japan?
- Any other details like exams required for applying for courses and Scholarships?

Comment: Please focus on one question, and choose one which is in the profile of this site. For example, we do not answer shopping questions. Have you contacted any university or laboratory inquiring about the doctoral programs?

Comment: @Greg I'm sorry, I'm new to this community. I have done a little research on Universities while I was thinking about my master, but not on Doctoral programs. I'll sure do that thanks.

Comment: Also, let’s address the elephant in the room: due to COVID, many foreign students (even the ones who were already accepted to universities), could not secure a visa and could not enter to Japan. No one knows how this will work out in the near future.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that you are being a bit naïve if you think that a 2-year Master gives you lots of time to properly plan for an application to study in Japan. In fact, 2 years is a very, very short amount of time. It is possible to apply, but please understand that you have a tremendous amount of work ahead of you (if you want to be successful), especially because you seem to have not done much research on the matter up until now.

Because your questions are too broad, I'm only going to reply to each of them as simple and short as possible. Even so, this is going to be a long answer.

**1. Application as a self-supported student**

First off, if you have enough money to pay full tuition fees and study in Japan as a self-supported student, then all you have to do is to check the universities' websites, they all have English websites and plenty of information about how to apply for their doctoral programs (including tuition fee info). In most cases, you will need to apply one year in advance (that is, just as you are starting your second year of master studies in India).

Note that competition for positions in the top "former imperial universities" is absolutely fierce (University of Tokyo, Kyoto University, Tohoku University, Kyushu University, Hokkaido University, Osaka University, Nagoya University). Unless you have excellent grades from your undergraduate and master programs, you will have some difficulty getting accepted in any of these top universities. It's not impossible to be accepted with average grades (for example Tohoku might be less competitive), but please do not think it will be by any means easy. Search for universities that offer doctoral programs completely in English, because it is impossible for you to master academic-level Japanese in just 2 years.
It would be also be wise for you to check webpages of polytechnic universities (basically any university that includes the word "Technology" in its name, such as Tokyo University of Technology).

**2. Application for Government Scholarships**

Please check the official website of MEXT and JASSO for information on Scholarships for foreign students, and how to apply for them. You can get started with these two websites:

[JASSO Website - Scholarships for Study in Japan](https://www.jasso.go.jp/en/study_j/scholarships/index.html)

[MEXT Website - Study in Japan](https://www.mext.go.jp/en/policy/education/highered/title02/detail02/sdetail02/1373897.htm)

Depending on the scholarship, you might need to apply one year or even 1.5 years in advance, so perhaps you are starting to realize how little time you actually have to prepare properly. There's going to be lots and lots of application forms, and you will need to get several certificates to prove your grades, etc.
Some scholarships such as MEXT Scholarship (by Embassy recommendation) will even ask you to do a personal interview at the embassy, and do two exams, one in high-level English, and another of high-level Japanese (comparable to JLPT N1 level). The results of the Japanese exam are only used to select between candidates who otherwise have the same score in the other tests and interview, so you don't need to score high on the Japanese exam. However, you will need to score extremely high on the English exam, and some embassies might ask you to do other exams, such as Math.

For most scholarships, if you get accepted you will be allowed to spend one year in a Japanese university as a "research student", which is a name used for people who are not officially registered in any program (i.e., neither undergraduate, master or doctoral), but are still allowed to use the premises of the university to prepare for the entrance exams. During that "research student" year, you have no ability to apply for any student discounts (university students have a 50% discount on public transportation, for example). While you are a research student, you will need to be as absolutely diligent as possible to study for the entrance exams every single day, and also learn as much Japanese as possible. If you think you are going to have an easy time and that you can do lots of sightseeing and party a lot and enjoy yourself, think again, because the exams are usually very tough and if you get lazy and start to procrastinate, there is no way you will pass them successfully and then your visa will expire and you will have to leave Japan. Please take the exams as seriously as possible, they must be your absolute priority at all times.

The number of Japanese universities that conduct entrance exams in English is relatively low, so that is the first thing you need to confirm in advance with each university, either by checking their website or sending an email to the Foreign Student office of each university. Besides the exams, you will have to do an interview with 3-5 professors about your research proposal in order to get accepted. Each professor can normally accept no more than 1-3 foreign doctoral students (depending on the size of the university), so you might be facing quite a lot of competition from other foreign students.

Once you finally pass the entrance exams and the interview, you will be officially admitted as a doctoral student instead of a mere "research student", and you can apply for student discounts and tuition fee waivers. Even then, you cannot lower your guard: every year you will need to write a report to prove to the scholarship providers that you are getting excellent grades in all classes, otherwise you will lose your scholarship and visa.

**3. Job prospects after getting the Doctoral Degree**

**3.1 Academia**

Unless you have a very high level of Japanese ability (Academic Japanese in the field of Engineering is actually at a higher level than JLPT N1), you will probably not get a position in academia in Japan. The number of academic positions available for non-Japanese speakers is incredibly small, and they are mainly intended for people who already have established careers abroad, and have accumulated lots of experience, publications, prizes and patents abroad. Either your research is extremely amazing, or you need to be incredibly lucky to get one of these positions (connections are everything in life).

**3.2 Private Companies**

Unlike academia, you may have some better chances getting hired with private companies, but please be aware that it's not an easy task, and in order to be successful you should be practicing your job interview and application skills during your 3-year Doctor course. If you wait until the last minute to prepare for job interviews, it is very unlikely that you will be successful. The secret to being successful in Japan is: prepare, prepare, PREPARE! And do your best to master engineering terms in Japanese (and academic Japanese in general), even now during your Master period. If you have 5 years of solid language training before you apply for jobs, you might be able to get something reasonable. Almost no Japanese company has any use for an earthquake engineer that can only speak English. You need to have other skills that can be of use to them.

Another important thing: the cultural attitudes of Japanese people are completely different than those in India. In Japan, devoting your time to the company is often more important than your own family (there are companies which do value family time and adopt a work-life balance principle, but they are relatively few and many people compete for such jobs). Depending on the time of the year, if you are working for major construction and engineering companies in a major Japanese city such as Tokyo, it is not rare for employees to do between 10-14 hours of work per day, and to work weekends and holidays. Many foreign students realize they cannot handle the pressure and end up returning to their countries, feeling bitter and frustrated. If you want less work hours, you will have to move to a small city or a more rural area, but then your salary and work conditions will also be much lower.

Beware of the so-called "black companies" which are notorious for deceiving applicants with false claims of good work conditions and then proceed to treat you like hell. There is some information about them online, but perhaps it is best to ask Japanese colleagues about such unlawful companies.

**4. Life in Japan**

**4.1. Budget**

The minimum amount of money per month necessary for surviving in Tokyo and Osaka is around 120-150.000 yen (150 thousand yen). This covers rent for a microscopic room (15-20 square meters) with a toilet and shower, water, internet, gas, electricity, transportation fees, and food. This amount of money is also what most scholarships offer, and it is very low. With just 120.000 yen, you will have to manage your monthly budget very carefully if you don't want to starve to death or become homeless. In a smaller city, you should be able to manage with 100.000 yen. If you cannot afford this much money per month (or find a scholarship that pays this much), you should not come to Japan. Don't expect to be sightseeing that much with this amount of money, travelling is very expensive! Use your money wisely. Don't forget about university tuition fees. Some scholarships such as MEXT can waive your tuition fees completely.

**4.2 Language and Culture**

This is perhaps the most difficult part of coming to Japan. Many, many foreigners come to Japan with enormous fantasies and illusions that have nothing to do with reality. They fantasize that they will be able to enjoy all sorts of cool things, cool technology and gadgets, and other rights and perks, while thinking that Japanese society is just going to accept them as they are, without needing to change anything about themselves and their cultural habits. They do not realize that in order to enjoy all of these cool things, perks and rights, there is an enormous list of duties, responsibilities and sacrifices that need to be made.

Do not naively assume that you can live in Japan in the same way as you live in India. Foreigners are expected to be extremely punctual at all times, they must not throw parties in their homes (the walls are thin, and your neighbors can hear every single thing you do!), and they must separate garbage diligently, and they must not damage anything in their rooms, or hang posters, etc. You might argue that there is a portion of Japanese citizens who are irresponsible and don't do any of these things. That is true, but if you are expecting Japanese society to accept you, you must be better and more reliable than the average Japanese, otherwise you will be kicked out of your rented room (and out of the country!) in no time.

If you are coming to Japan, you must come with the attitude that you must adapt to their culture. To be clear, you don't need to change every single cultural habit you have, but nobody is going to extend a red carpet on your arrival and treat you nicely unless you go a long way towards mastering their language and the key aspects of their cultural behaviors, especially punctuality and dedication to work and self-improvement, and dedication to helping your fellow students, coworkers and the company as a whole. In a number of large Japanese companies, most decisions are not made at meetings, but rather in informal gatherings at restaurants or bars where people can loosen up and speak more freely. The meetings are mostly used as performances just to confirm what was already decided at the drinking parties. Meetings are not the place to challenge the decisions of your supervisor or your boss. If you think that there is something that needs to be changed or could be done better, wait patiently until the meeting is over, and quietly chat with a trusted co-worker or send a polite email to your supervisor, suggesting a different way how things could be done. Then let the co-worker/supervisor go behind the scenes in order to try to get some consensus around your idea. Don't automatically expect it to be accepted, and don't expect to get any credit or recognition for your idea, especially if your supervisor had to do all of the convincing work to get it adopted. That's how life is there, and if you continue contributing, and learning the language better, over time you will probably have increasing opportunities to make a difference and get some recognition.

If you manage to connect with the Indian community that is already living in Japan, you might be able to find some job through their connections, and maybe get by without having to change your cultural habits, but then you might also lose access to some good-paying jobs, and you might also have a harder time mastering the language, and you will also feel very isolated from the rest of society as a whole. It's something that you will have to consider deeply once you arrive here. Remember that Japanese employers deeply value those employees who can interact well with Japanese customers. If you can speak the language well and understand well their polite cultural norms, and have proven yourself to be reliable, diligent and responsible, then that's how you can get the best-paid jobs. Otherwise, you risk ending up in poorly-paid jobs that will stress you and drain your life away, little by little.

Good luck, and work/study hard.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir, it was quite informative and valuable.

Comment: Phd programs in STEM generally do not require any Japanese skills, and have no course work. In fact, universities have special courses from beginner level (mostly packed with master and phd students), which is also part of most sponsored programs, too.

Comment: This is an amazing answer! I wish it were attached to a better question. We don't normally encourage duplicate answers, but in this case, please feel free to copy anything from this answer into other `japan`-tagged questions. If you'd be interested in contributing to a canonical question along the lines of "So you want to do a PhD in Japan", please let us know; East Asian Academia is one place where this site tends to get more questions than answers.

Comment: Thank you for all of the above comments. I will consider applying for a canonical question in the future, but due to current work commitments, it will take a while. Hopefully, this answer will be enough to satisfy most inquiries for the time being.